# javascript table format output

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have this JavaScript html code for getting the tabular format output. I am giving XML data as input to the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(
  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
  +"<book>"+
  "<title>The Time Machine and Other Stories</title>"+
  "<author_name>H. G. Wells</author_name>"+
  "<publish_date>2016</publish_date>"+
  "<cost currency=\"USD\">10</cost>"+
  "<publisher_info>"+ 
  "<publisher_name>Read Books Ltd</publisher_name>"+
  "<publisher_address>"+
  "<street_name>Evesham street</street_name>"+
  "<city>Worcestershire</city>"+
  "<zip_code>11WR</zip_code>"+
  "<country>United Kingdom</country>"+
  "</publisher_address>"+
  "</publisher_info>"+
  "</book>","text/xml");

  var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("publisher_address");
  
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
    document.write("<tr>");
    var y=x[i].childNodes;
    for (j=0;j<y.length;j++) {
      document.write("<td>"+ y[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue+ "</td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
  }
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>My First XML Parsing JavaScript</h1>
<p>Click the button to display book info.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<table border="0">
</table>
```

The output I am getting is:

> Evesham streetWorcestershire11WRUnited Kingdom

Can anyone help me why I am not able to get output in tabular format?

Comment: Because of [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) It is not allowed on an XML page.

Comment: how can I display the results in tabular format then?

Comment: You create the table with proper DOM manipulation methods, like `createElement` and `appendChild`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `document.write()`which does not gives you expected output.

Use `createElement` to create a table, fill the data by creating rows, and td's and append to your dom or your paragraph.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>My First XML Parsing JavaScript</h1>
  <p>Click the button to display book info.</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <table border="0">
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(
          "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
          "<book>" +
          "<title>The Time Machine and Other Stories</title>" +
          "<author_name>H. G. Wells</author_name>" +
          "<publish_date>2016</publish_date>" +
          "<cost currency=\"USD\">10</cost>" +
          "<publisher_info>" +
          "<publisher_name>Read Books Ltd</publisher_name>" +
          "<publisher_address>" +
          "<street_name>Evesham street</street_name>" +
          "<city>Worcestershire</city>" +
          "<zip_code>11WR</zip_code>" +
          "<country>United Kingdom</country>" +
          "</publisher_address>" +
          "</publisher_info>" +
          "</book>", "text/xml");
          
         // creating a table 
         table = document.createElement('table');

        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("publisher_address");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          
          // create a row
          var tr = table.insertRow();
    
          var y = x[i].childNodes;
          for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {

           // crate a cell for your data
           var td = tr.insertCell();
           
           // put the data into your td
           td.innerHTML = y[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

          }
        }
        // append it to body, or to your p#demo
        document.body.appendChild(table);

      }
    </script>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this isn't the answer. Is there any way to put the results into a table?

Comment: You need to make use of `createElement`, `appendChild` or use table functions such as `insertRow()`, `insertCell()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your table a container with an ID to hook to:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="my-table-contents"></tbody>
</table>
```

Then in your javascript you can append to that container.

```
<script>
  var myTable = document.getElementById('my-table-contents');

  function myFunction() {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(
      "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
      "<book>" +
      "<title>The Time Machine and Other Stories</title>" +
      "<author_name>H. G. Wells</author_name>" +
      "<publish_date>2016</publish_date>" +
      "<cost currency=\"USD\">10</cost>" +
      "<publisher_info>" +
      "<publisher_name>Read Books Ltd</publisher_name>" +
      "<publisher_address>" +
      "<street_name>Evesham street</street_name>" +
      "<city>Worcestershire</city>" +
      "<zip_code>11WR</zip_code>" +
      "<country>United Kingdom</country>" +
      "</publisher_address>" +
      "</publisher_info>" +
      "</book>", "text/xml");

    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("publisher_address");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      myTable.innerHtml += "<tr>";
      var y = x[i].childNodes;
      for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {

        myTable.innerHtml += "<td>" + y[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td>";

      }
      myTable.innerHtml += "</tr>";
    }

  }
</script>
```